# Configuring gRPC to use SSL package doesn't work on first build

Tags: linux, cmake, openssl, grpc, cross-compiling

I'm building gRPC on Linux and want to use OpenSSL for the SSL provider. My CMakeLists.txt has these lines:

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
set(gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER package)
```

On a clean build, it has compile errors because it tries to build "boringssl" and some of its symbols conflict with the OpenSSL headers. I want it to use the OpenSSL package and not try to build boringssl at all.

After this first failed build, the CMakeCache.txt contains this line:

```
gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER:STRING=module
```

If I build it again, it then uses OpenSSL, doesn't try to build boringssl, and builds successfully. If I delete the line above or the whole CMakeCache.txt file, the errors return.

How do I make it use OpenSSL and not boringssl on the first build?

In case it makes a difference, I'm cross compiling for arm64 using dockcross.

EDIT:

@Tsyvarev: my CMakeLists.txt sets some options and then downloads gRPC using FetchContent, so I'm using the main CMakeLists.txt in the gRPC project.

Comment: gRPC provides ready CMake project, so it is not clear where do you put your code. Or do you have your own project, where you add gRPC project via `add_subdirectory`? Please, clarify that in the question post.

Comment: "my CMakeLists.txt sets some options and then downloads gRPC using FetchContent" - Do not *describe* your code; instead add the code into the question post as is, in form of [mcve]. (GRPC has a complex configuration, so every detail in your code could matter.)